# Calling method in MapRoute MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

Is it possible to pass a parameter from "url" section to a method in "default" section of MapRoute?

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Language",
               url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}-{description}",
               defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, language = UrlParameter.Optional, description = GetDescription(id) }
           );
```

I am able to call GetDescription() without any parameters but I dont know how to pass a parameter from url ie. GetDescription(id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have misunderstood the concept of route definition. You cannot add dynamic behavior into rote registration process because it is executed only once on [application start event](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs). The defaults parameter is used when the routing engine does not find a appropriate parameter in the provided URL. What are you trying to do is possible on url generation level:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { language = "en", id=5, description = "test" })
```

Comment: I see, so instead of handling it in route, would want to create a helper that would create description for particular url type.

Comment: @mko yes, you can create a custom helper

Comment: I have added a question that is linked with this one, maybe you can answer it.